# Evaluate $\int_C (x+y) \,\mathrm{d}x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I want to evaluate the the following line integral:
$$\int_C (x+y) \,\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $C$ is the semicircle starting at $(0,1)$ and ending at $(0,-1)$ as shown below:

[image]

Is there a function of $y$ that I can replace it with to be be able to solve this?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.  Have you tried polar coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parametric equations,$$ x=\sin t, y= \cos t$$ for  $ t$ from $0$ to $\pi $

Substitute  these values  for $x$ and $y$ and evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterizing $C$, since the direction is clockwise we have:
\begin{equation}
-C=\begin{cases} x(t)=Cost \\ y(t)=Sint \end{cases}, t\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]
\end{equation}
now, $dx(t)=-Sin(t)$$dt$ and for line integral properties:

$\int_{-C}=-\int_{C}$

so we have
\begin{equation}
-\int_{-C}(x+y)dx=-\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(Cost+Sint)(-Sint)dt=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(Cost+Sint)(Sint)dt=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}

Comment: The way you've parameterized here would make t vary so that $-\pi/2 < t < \pi/2$

Comment: True, I took the upper semicircle, anyway result does not change. I've corrected the bounds